# Nginx split URI before proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass, imagefilter

I'm trying to split a URI in nginx in order to break it down into components. I'll explain why as we go along. Take this url:

```
http://example.com/resize/customer-id/image.jpg/100/100/
```

What I need to do now is split that URI into components so I can manipulate it.

for example I what to send a proxy_pass to:

```
http://backend/customer-id/image.jpg
```

This is dropping the resize part of the location match and the two end components.

The values at the end I'm actually wishing to use with:

```
image_filter resize $3 $4
```

If anyone knows the answer can you help please i'm going round in circles at the moment!

Cheers Ric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, as an example.
Next you can use variables in location.

```
if ($uri ~ ^/resize(/customer-id/image.jpg)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ {
    set $path1 $1; 
    set $w $2;
    set $h $3;
}
```